# pydantic: JSON dictionary type?

Tags: python, pydantic

I want to use `pydantic` to validate that some incoming data is a valid JSON dictionary. There is already the predefined `pydantic.Json` type but this seems to be only for validating Json strings. Then of course I could use `Dict[str, Any]` but that allows values that are not valid in JSON. What I really want is the following:

```py
from typing import (
    Dict,
    List,
    Union,
)

from pydantic import (
    BaseModel,
)

Json = Union[None, str, int, bool, List['Json'], Dict[str, 'Json']]

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    field: Json
```

But that fails with a recursion error. How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/types/#pydantic.types.JsonValue are you sure you don't just want `Dict[str, 'JsonValue']` ?

Comment: @Anentropic Yes, that looks like what I want. Can you make that into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Pydantic has an appropriate type for this:

https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/types/#pydantic.types.JsonValue

> ### JsonValue module-attribute ¶
>
> ```py
> JsonValue = Union[
>     List["JsonValue"],
>     Dict[str, "JsonValue"],
>     str,
>     bool,
>     int,
>     float,
>     None,
> ]
> ```
>
> A JsonValue is used to represent a value that can be serialized to JSON.
>
> It may be one of:
>
> - `List['JsonValue']`
> - `Dict[str, 'JsonValue']`
> - `str`
> - `bool`
> - `int`
> - `float`
> - `None`
>
> The
> following example demonstrates how to use JsonValue to validate JSON
> data, and what kind of errors to expect when input data is not json
> serializable.
>
> ```py
> import json
>
> from pydantic import BaseModel, JsonValue, ValidationError
>
> class Model(BaseModel):
>     j: JsonValue
> ```

So if you want something typed as expecting a JSON object then you could use `Dict[str, JsonValue]`